# NOT NULL constraint failed with bulk insert

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I found that I have troubles using parametrized insert statements with sqlite3 version [4.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3/v/4.1.0). Here's a basic example demonstrating the error:

```js
let sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");

let data = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3]
];

let db = new sqlite3.Database(":memory:")
    .run(`CREATE TABLE TEST(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    count INTEGER NOT NULL,
    xPos REAL NOT NULL,
    yPos REAL NOT NULL
)`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            insertRecords();
        }
    });

insertRecords = () => {
    db.all(`INSERT INTO TEST(count, xPos, yPos) VALUES(?,?,?)`, data, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                console.log(rows[i]);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

If I execute that code, I will get errors along the following lines:

```
[Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: TEST.count] {
  errno: 19,
  code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT'
}
```

The problem occures on the first line in `insertRecords`. There I try to push several records into the DB, using an array of data. According to several sources, this should be the way to go.

It seems that no matter what I do, the parameter `data` doesn't seem to be parsed correctly. I tried similar constructs with prepared statements and other methods that allow me to pass a `params` parameter.

Now it's obviously very possible that I'm doing something stupid, but I tested quite a few things and I'm out of ideas. Does anybody else have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add placeholders `(?,?,?)` for each row in the `data`.

Change the beginning of `insertRecords` function to:

```
const placeHolders = data.map((row) => '(?,?,?)').join(',');

db.all(`INSERT INTO TEST(count, xPos, yPos) VALUES ${placeHolders}`, data, (err, rows) => {
```

See [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/insert/) for more info

If you want to write and manipulate queries easily - try [knex](https://knexjs.org/), it will save you a lot of this trouble.

Your case for example:

```
let data = [
  {count: 1, xPos: 1, yPos: 1},
  {count: 2, xPos: 2, yPos: 2},
  {count: 3, xPos: 3, yPos: 3}
];
db.insert(data).into('test').then(result => {})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, it doesn't quite seem to do the trick, I still get the same error after incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: I tested it before posting, I didn't get any error.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, check now

Comment: I did see the typo before. Did you by any chance change the data array? It seems I got it working when I flatted that and using your suggestions.

Comment: I didn't touch the data array. I'm happy that you got it working. It will be great if you will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Obviously, as it was your comment that made the final difference. Thanks